# Subquery in MS Query doesn't work

Tags: subquery, ms-query

I'm a beginner in SQL. I hope my question is not too stupid.

I'm trying to write a query in MS Query and want to see the results in Excel.
The problem is that MS Query doesn't accept my code. I get the message:

> table '(select' couldn't be added.

Here's the code:

```
SELECT  
    T1.Jahr, 
        T1.Monat, 
        T1.Land_ID, 
        T1.Kanal, 
        T1.Items_per_HC, 
        T1.Planstand, 
        T1.Zeitraum,
        T2.Zeitraum,
        T2.LAND_ID,
        T2.KANAL,
        T2.IST_ITEMS_PER_HC_EXCL_EASY 
FROM 
(SELECT tPLAN.Jahr, tPLAN.Monat, tPLAN.Land_ID, tPLAN.Kanal, 
        tPLAN.Items_per_HC, tPLAN.Planstand, tZ.Zeitraum
    FROM t_Plan_Items_per_HC tPLAN, t_PLAN_ZEITRAUM tZ
    WHERE tPLAN.Jahr = tZ.Jahr 
    AND tPLAN.Monat = tZ.Monat) as T1
INNER JOIN a_ITEMS_PER_CALL_ACT_MONTH_KANAL_EXCL_EASY_HC AS T2 
  ON (T1.Zeitraum=T2.Zeitraum 
  AND T1.Land_ID=T2.LAND_ID 
  AND T1.Kanal=T2.KANAL)
```

What is wrong?

I have to see the content of table *t_Plan_Items_per_HC* and table *a_ITEMS_PER_CALL_ACT_MONTH_KANAL_EXCL_EASY_HC* in only one table. They should be joined by *Land_ID*, *Zeitraum*, and *KANAL*.

UPDATE: Now I tried the same code in SQL Developer and it works. It seems to be an MS Query-specific problem. Unfortunately I have to solve this problem in MS Query so I still need help.

Comment: Why don't you create a view and just call the view from MSQuery?

Comment: Does MS_Query allow multiple table joins? If yes, you could eliminate the subquery, using a simple 3-table join.

Answer (score 1):

Your query can be simplified (regardless of `SQL` flavor) not to use an inner query (subselect). This is not tested, but it should be closer to what you need:

```
SELECT tPLAN.Jahr, tPLAN.Monat, tPLAN.Land_ID, tPLAN.Kanal, T1.tPLAN, tPLAN.Planstand, 
    tZ.Zeitraum, T2.IST_ITEMS_PER_HC_EXCL_EASY 
FROM t_Plan_Items_per_HC tPLAN 
    JOIN t_PLAN_ZEITRAUM tZ ON tZ.Jahr = tPLAN.Jahr AND tZ.Monat = tPLAN.Monat
    JOIN a_ITEMS_PER_CALL_ACT_MONTH_KANAL_EXCL_EASY_HC AS T2 
        ON (T2.Zeitraum=tZ.Zeitraum AND T2.Land_ID=tPLAN.LAND_ID AND T2.Kanal=tPLAN.KANAL)
```

Since all `JOIN`s are `INNER`, you can just select from one of the tables and `JOIN` with each of the others using your criteria. Also, `WHERE` conditions like:

```
FROM t_Plan_Items_per_HC tPLAN, t_PLAN_ZEITRAUM tZ
    WHERE tPLAN.Jahr = tZ.Jahr 
    AND tPLAN.Monat = tZ.Monat)
```

are not recommended. Use `JOIN`s instead.